# How to identify which Dynamic Checkbox is Checked dynamically in C# WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, wpf-controls

In my WPF application, I displayed some `Checkbox` dynamically. The `Name` and `Content` of these `Checkbox` come from a Table in the Database.

```
...
StackPanel innerStack = new StackPanel();
        List<Course> courses = ldc.Courses.ToList();
        var count = courses.Count();
        var b = ldc.Books.Single(x=>x.BookID==1);
        foreach (var c in courses)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.Name = c.CourseID.ToString();
            cb.Content = c.CourseID.ToString();
            var x = from bc in ldc.CourseAndBooks
                    where bc.BookID == b.BookID
                    select bc.CourseID;
            if (x.Contains(c.CourseID))
            {
                cb.IsChecked = true;
            }

            cb.AddHandler(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(course_Checked));
            cb.AddHandler(CheckBox.UncheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(course_Unchecked));
            innerStack.Children.Add(cb);
        }
        Grid.SetColumn(innerStack,0);
        Grid.SetRow(innerStack,0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(innerStack,1);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(innerStack,1);
        grid.Children.Add(innerStack);
        ...
```

I added `Checked` and `Unchecked` event too to manipulate the checked item in the Database.

```
 private void course_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("checked"); // it works
        // How to identify cb.Name here to perform some database query?
    }
    private void course_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unchecked"); // it works
        // How to identify cb.Name here to perform some database query?
    }
```

So, how can I get the name of the checked/unchecked `Checkbox` name in the Checked/Unchecked` event method. Any suggession ? Thankyou.

Comment: Can't you directly access it on the sender ? ((CheckBox)sender).Name

Comment: Is there any reasonable argument why you're sticking controls in a procedural code?

Comment: @PiotrPtak He's dynamically generating them based on the courses.  How else might you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly sure you can cast the sender to a CheckBox and it will be what you're looking for.